# Grid lines extending too far

Tags: plotting, grid-lines

The grid lines in the following plot extend beyond the data and, in particular, into the numbers along the axis.

```
BarChart[{{1,2,3},{3,1,2}},BarSpacing->{0,2}]
Show[%,GridLines->{None,Range[3]}]
```

[image]

### Question

Why does this happen?  What can be done to keep the grid lines from going left of the vertical axis?

Comment: Try `PlotRangePadding->None`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Essentially the Axis is in the wrong place.  A more dramatic example:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}},
 BarSpacing -> {0, 2},
 GridLines -> {None, Range[3]}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {3, 0}
]
```

[image]

You can correct this with [`PlotRangePadding -> 0`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRangePadding.html) (as already proposed) or you can use a [`Frame`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Frame.html) instead:

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}},
 BarSpacing -> {0, 2},
 GridLines -> {None, Range[3]}, 
 Frame -> Left
]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, both solutions work for the example I gave, but this one continues to work after adding the option `PlotRange -> {0, 4})` but the other solution no longer works.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard nice explaination so +1 :D

Comment: @JunhoLee Thank you.  I also voted for your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PlotRangePadding->None` as `Option` of `Graphics`.

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}}, BarSpacing -> {0, 2}, 
 GridLines -> {None, Range[3]}, PlotRangePadding -> None]
```

> [image]

version 8 makes the same result @Mr.Wizard 's comment as `Range[0, 3]`

```
BarChart[{{1, 2, 3}, {3, 1, 2}}, BarSpacing -> {0, 2}, 
 GridLines -> {None, Range[0, 3]}, Frame -> Left]
```

> [image]

Comment: I don't think this answers the question

Comment: @Verbeia I made misunderstand and corrected. thanks again. :)

Comment: For version 8 change `Range[3]` to `Range[0, 3]`. :-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard thanks a lot.